# Custom UITableView Section not increasing height

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to make a custom TableView Section. That is higher than the normal section header.

The problem is when i example increase the height from 18 to 30. Nothing happen it does not get any bigger. What am i doing wrong?

i have this code:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
    /* Create custom view to display section header... */
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    NSString *string =[[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"league"];
    /* Section header is in 0th index... */
    [label setText:string];
    [view addSubview:label];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:166/255.0 green:177/255.0 blue:186/255.0 alpha:1.0]]; //your background color...
    return view;
}
```

Comment: See UITableViewDelegate `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement this method :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 18.0; // whatever height you want
}
```

If you are using iOS 7, you can use implemeent the following method also :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```